# Get error when opening project in Blend VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, blend

I've just created a basic windows app project in Visual Studio. I right click the html file and open in blend.

I get this error in blend when trying to do this :

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Any ideas ?

I have tried running as administrator on both VS and blend and this doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. I went to control panel, programs & features, right clicked windows visual studio and repaired it, that was it.

Not too sure what the problem was but this solved it :)